# Character Encoding in Java

Tags: java

In eclipse, I changed the default encoding to ISO-8859-1. Then I wrote this:

```
String str = "Русский язык ";
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
ps.print(str);
```

It should print the `String` correctly, as I am specifying `UTF-8` encoding. However, it is not printing.

Comment: Does flushing / closing the stream help?

Comment: But what exactly did you set in Eclipse? The default encoding used for source code files? If so, this has nothing to do with Java runtime's default encoding for `PrintStream`. I wonder how the characters "Русский язык " can even be saved in ISO-8859-1. Does Eclipse automatically convert to `\uxxxx` syntax?

Comment: Default encoding was UTF-8 only, i changed to ISO-8859-1.Then used PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8"); It should print unicode characters, but not printing.On changing default encoding back to UTF-8, its working,Then what is the use of PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8"); to change default encoding.

Comment: OP, I asked what exactly do you mean when you say "default encoding"? What Eclipse setting exactly? BTW I've just tried setting source code encoding to ISO-8859-1 and saving with that string in it, it threw an error stating that those chars cannot be represented by the chosen encoding. So please OP, **what exactly Eclipse setting do you mean**?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik In Eclipse you can choose the encoding of the source file.

Comment: ya marko, i changed the java file properties to ISO-8859-1, eclipse could not save unicode characters if encoding is ISO-8859-1. So it printed some junk characters in place of unicode characters. But in PrintStream constructor i am mentining UTF-8 encoding, but it is not printing those unicode characters, I appolize if it is a dumb questions, i just wanted to get a solution.

Comment: OK, Ritesh. Then look up @Matteo's answer below. As soon as you save your file in ISO-8859-1, that file **does not contain your Russian characters**. Instead it contains the junk characters that you see after reopening the file. The compiler, the bytecode, and the runtime see those junk characters. There is no way to recover the original characters, at the time your code runs they are long lost already. All you achieve by setting the encoding on the `PrintStream` is affecting the way the Unicode characters in Java will be converted into bytes before being sent to the `OutputStream`.

Comment: Sir, thnx for reply, it was helpfull, now since in PrintStream also we can set the encoding, how it is different form PrintWriter( other than - PrintStream is a byte stream and PrintWriter is a character Stream).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ISO-8859-1` character encoding only supports characters between 0 and 255, and anything else is likely to be turned into '?'

Comment: Thnx for reply peter, But in PrintStream constructor i am giving encoding as UTF-8 ?

Comment: But the display assumes you are writing ISO-8859-1 because that is what you set it to. It has to turn the bytes you produce from the PrintStream and turn them back into characters.

Answer (score 4):

If you save the source file (the `.java` file) as ISO-8859-1 than `str` will be encoded by javac using ISO-8859-1. Your problem does not lie in the creation of `PrintStream`: the `str` you are printing is wrong from the beginning.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Of course it has. I had exacly the same problem. Eclipse is saving the file as ISO-8859-1 and if you check the bytecode of the compiled class you will not find what you except. I searched for days an encoding problem in an integration test before realising the the problem was not in Hibernate, PostgreSQL but simply in the encoding of my test file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it looks like the terminal that your are sending this output does not support this encoding.

If you are running Eclipse, you could set the encoding as follows:

- In Run Configurations...->Common ->Encoding->Other
- Select UTF-8

Comment: Thnx for reply, Default encoding was UTF-8 only, i changed to ISO-8859-1.Then used PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8"); It should print unicode characters, but not printing.On changing default encoding back to UTF-8, its working,Then what is the use of PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8"); to change default encoding.

Comment: The encoding produces the specific characters from bytes but your 'terminal' has to be set to interpret them properly.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically telling the PrintStream writer to expect the input characters to be UTF-8 encoded and to output it as UTF-8. There is no conversion. If you set your IDE to use ISO-8859-1 as character encoding for your file, which in turns contains the input string than you pipe ISO-8859-1 encoded characters into an UTF-8 expecting writer. So the writer treats the bytes receiving as UTF encoded characters which will result in data junk.

Either set your IDE to encode your source files in UTF-8 and check that your characters are correctly displayed and stored. Or tell your writer to treat them as ISO-8859-1, either way should do.

Comment: This answer confuses and conflates source file encoding with runtime encoding. They have nothing to do with each other, there is no **conversion** between the two. Java Strings are made of Unicode characters in the abstract sense, they are not encoded in any way.

Comment: Partially correct. Yes java internal it is UTF16. But if the IDE is converting the (unicode characters) to ISO byte representation on disk, there is going to be messed up characters in the java strings. Such that they result in "non" UTF-16 characters in runtime while printing. How would the JVM be able to figure out how the input string in the sourcefile is encoded? It just reads the bytes, which in case are codes meant for ISO not for UTF.

Comment: No, java chars are not **encoded** in UTF-16, they only support the same charset. For example, it is not defined whether they are big-endian or little-endian. They don't decompose into two bytes.

Comment: "This is because the language's internal representation of characters uses the UTF-16 encoding" see (fairly old but quite sure didn't change) [Javadoc Charset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html)

Comment: Yes, there is a higher-level encoding to UTF-16 regarding supplementary characters. This is all in terms of 16-bit words. Note that there is no inherent **byte encoding** to those 16-bit words, and byte encoding is the subject we are discussing.