# Java Unicode Characters after u 00ff

Tags: java, eclipse, unicode

I can not print the unicode values after 00ff Instead I'm getting '?' character after execution of this in Eclipse. Is that an expectable behaviour?

```
System.out.println("\u01ff");
```

Comment: I believe this has to do with your file encoding, try writing it to a file and open it with an editor like notepad if on win or just go and check your encoding in the preferences

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eclipse uses by default platform default encoding (which is cp1252 in Windows) to decode characters during saving textbased files and during writing to standard output stream (as used by `System.out`). You need to explicitly set it to UTF-8 in order to achieve world domination.

[image]

Note that this way you also don't need to use those `\uXXXX` Unicode escapes anymore to represent those characters in your textbased source files.

Those question marks are caused because the charset as used by the output stream does not support the character as specified in the input stream.

#### See also:

- [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)

Comment: This will not help when the program is run outside Eclipse.

Comment: "Note that this way you also don't need to use those \uXXXX Unicode escapes anymore to represent those characters in your textbased source files."  Unless you ever want anyone else to compile your program.

Comment: @Ted: I didn't imply otherwise. If you need to run it outside Eclipse, just configure that runtime environment accordingly. The program itself shouldn't be responsible for configuring the runtime environment. If you absolutely need to present the characters the way you intented, just use a Swing frame or so instead of writing to the stdout which you've no control over.

Comment: @Mike: We're at 2013. UTF-8 exists for more than a decade already. I'd be rather more surprised seeing a modern project to not use UTF-8 for source code files.

Comment: OP's problem is that the output isn't supporting Unicode characters. Your answer deals with using Unicode characters in the source code (and maybe the default `System.out` encoding when running in Eclipse). That's why I think it doesn't addresses OP's problem. Your comment about the environment is valid, but that info is missing from your answer. Also, not all environments allow you to specify `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` on the command line or to set the `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` environment variable to include `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8`. Much better to exert explicit control from within the code.

Comment: @Ted: all nice and well, just create a JAR. By the way, your answer doesn't fix the problem in Eclipse as described by the OP. Did you really try it yourself?

Comment: @BalusC - Oops. It worked fine when I ran it outside Eclipse. I did try it in Eclipse, but the default encoding was already UTF-8 so it of course also worked fine. You're right that it won't work with an encoding of, say, ISO-8859-1. The correct UTF-8 encoding of `\u01ff` (`0xC7 0xBF`) is written to `System.out` but the output is "Ç¿" (the ISO-8859-1 interpretation of `0xC7 0xBF`). I still think that exerting explicit control inside the code is better than using a command line option. How will "just create a JAR" help? You still need to specify the encoding on the command line.

Comment: @BalusC, Until most people compile with `-encoding` it doesn't matter what year it is.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the encoding used with `System.out`; by default, it's your platform's native encoding (usually not UTF-8). You can explicitly change the encoding by replacing the stream:

```
try {
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
    System.setOut(ps);
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException error) {
    System.err.println(error);
}
```

After this (barring font or encoding issues with the underlying environment), all Unicode characters should print correctly on `System.out`.

**EDIT** Based on the back-and-forth between me and BalusC on [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18046507/535871), this isn't enough (or even necessary) to get things working inside Eclipse. There you have two problems to solve: using the correct encoding when writing to `System.out` and then using the correct encoding when presenting the console output in the Eclipse console view. BalusC's answer addresses both of those issues. Unfortunately, it won't address running outside Eclipse. For that, you need to either use my approach above or set the default run-time encoding. This can be done by using the flag `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` on the command line or setting the environment variable `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` to include `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`. To run your code successfully outside Eclipse, then that's probably the best approach.

Comment: This doesn't work at all. This just tells the stream which encoding to use to encode the characters fed to it. It doesn't tell the stdout console ("the other side") which encoding to use to decode them from the stream. It's completely beyond me why this answer got 3 upvotes so far. Are there so many nitwits on SO? Related Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12061418/character-encoding-in-java

Comment: @BalusC - That's rather harsh. Your answer doesn't work at all _outside_ Eclipse, but I don't consider the 4 upvotes you got so far to be from nitwits.

Comment: This needs to be configured on a per runtime environment basis. There is no single answer which covers all runtime environments. OP used Eclipse, so I answered specifically for that.

Answer (score 0):

Java can handle those characters just fine. But the outputs team will have a specific encoding.

And unless that encoding is something like UTF-8 or UTF-16, it won't be able to encode every character in Unicode.  And when it encounters a character it can't represent,  it will be replaced with a question mark.

Answer (score 0):

The JVM uses the default file encoding for `System.out` as well.

On Linux for example, if your `$LANG` variable is set to `de_DE.UTF-8`, the value for `file.encoding` will be derived accordingly, and set to `utf-8`.

If the JVM cannot derive the setting you want, you can change the file encoding by setting a system property:

> java -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 ...

on the command line.

You can do this as well in *Eclipse* using a *Run configuration* (context menu - Run as - Run configurations ... - Arguments - VM arguments)

So this works both for the command line and *Eclipse*, and there is no need to define the encoding explicitly in the source.

---

If the value is set to

> java -Dfile.encoding=iso-8859-1

for example, only a subset of the Unicode characters can be represented, because that character set only supports a limited number of characters. The other ones will turn up as `?`.

---

There are two other things to bear in mind:

- The device which receives the stream (a terminal, shell etc.) must decode it correctly. As for GNOME's terminal for example, you can set the character encoding in a menu.
- The font being used by that terminal etc. must contain the graphical representation for this character